# change height of programmatically created custom inputAccessoryView? swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, inputaccessoryview

So I'm making a messaging app, and I have 4 class properties:

1. `typingView: UIView!`
2. `messageTextView: UITextView!`
3. `sendButton: UIButton!`
4. `typingViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint?`

The `typingView` is the `inputAccessoryView` of the main view, which works! It contains the `messageTextView` and `sendButton`. But my problem is...when the number of lines of text in the `messageTextView` increases, **I want the height to increase with an animation** (I'm ignoring decreasing for now). And by doing that, I decided to change the height of the `typingView`.

Detecting a change in contentSize works perfectly, I added an observer by 
 adding this line

```
messageTextView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
```

and listened to it with this override

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
```

Inside of this function, I have (this is an over simplification and pseudocode, just assume it works)

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: keyboardAnimationDuration) {
    self.typingViewHeight?.constaint += (messageTextView.font?.lineHeight)!
}
```

Here is my code for the customizing the `inputAccessoryView`:

```
lazy var typingViewContainer: UIView = {
    // Set up typing view
    typingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 55))
    typingView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    typingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // Set up animated constraints
    typingViewHeight = typingView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: typingView.frame.height)
    typingViewHeight?.isActive = true

    // Set up text view
    messageTextView = UITextView()
    messageTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    messageTextView.font = fakeMessageTextView.font
    messageTextView.keyboardType = fakeMessageTextView.keyboardType
    messageTextView.isScrollEnabled = fakeMessageTextView.isScrollEnabled
    messageTextView.alwaysBounceVertical = fakeMessageTextView.alwaysBounceVertical
    messageTextView.text = fakeMessageTextView.text
    messageTextView.textColor = fakeMessageTextView.textColor
    messageTextView.delegate = self
    typingView.addSubview(messageTextView)

    // Constraints
    messageTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: typingView.bottomAnchor, constant: -fakeMessageTextViewBottom.constant).isActive = true
    messageTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: typingView.topAnchor, constant: fakeMessageTextViewTop.constant).isActive = true
    messageTextView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: typingView.leftAnchor, constant: fakeMessageTextViewBottom.constant).isActive = true
    messageTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: fakeMessageTextViewWidth.constant).isActive = true

    // Observers
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)  
    messageTextView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)

    // Set up send button
    sendButton = UIButton(type: fakeSendButton.buttonType)
    sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sendButton.setTitle(fakeSendButton.titleLabel?.text!, for: .normal)
    sendButton.titleLabel?.font = fakeSendButton.titleLabel?.font
    sendButton.titleLabel?.shadowColor = fakeSendButton.titleLabel?.shadowColor
    sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    typingView.addSubview(sendButton)

    // Constraints
    sendButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: fakeSendButtonHeight.constant).isActive = true
    sendButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: fakeSendButtonWidth.constant).isActive = true
    sendButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: typingView.bottomAnchor, constant: -fakeSendButtonBottom.constant).isActive = true
    sendButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: typingView.rightAnchor, constant: -fakeSendButtonRight.constant).isActive = true

    return typingView
}()

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    get {
        return typingViewContainer
    }
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    get {
        return true
    }
}
```

But when I test this and typing in multiple lines, it prints out this in the console:

```
2018-04-25 08:52:57.614383-0500 ProxiChat[3351:168967] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000280a50 UIView:0x7f8528a2cda0.height == 73   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040000993c0 UIView:0x7f8528a2cda0.height == 55   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000280a50 UIView:0x7f8528a2cda0.height == 73   
(active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

**Why are there two constraints? I only added one.** Please help, thanks!

**EDIT**

Assume that my code for changing the height of the `typingView` works, since it worked before I changed my view to be a custom inputAccessoryView. I just want to know why it's printing out that error, and how I can fix it from setting two constraints, even though I only added one?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem? I am in exact situation and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not appear to be possible. Sorry, it's an iOS limitation!

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the view you are setting the height as 55:

```
typingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 55))
```

And then you are setting a height anchor:

```
typingViewHeight = typingView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: typingView.frame.height)
typingViewHeight?.isActive = true
```

That would be why you are seeing a conflict. Another observation is when setting a height anchor you can activate it in the same line it is created:

```
typingViewHeight = typingView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: typingView.frame.height).isActive = true
```

This keeps you from writing an extra line of code every time

Comment: You cannot do that to get a constraint `typingViewHeight = typingView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: typingView.frame.height).isActive = true`

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Also if I try `typingView = UIView()`, instead of `"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040000993c0 UIView:0x7f8528a2cda0.height == 55   (active)>"` it says `"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040000993c0 UIView:0x7f8528a2cda0.height == 0   (active)>"`. Even when I created a UIView() with no init, it sets a default height to zero?

Answer (score 0):

**First things first**

Instead of observation I recommend that you use `UITextView`'s delegate method to adjust the height of the container and your text view. That code does the same trick, but I think it's more concise and clean.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let sizeToFitIn = CGSize(width: textView.bounds.size.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(sizeToFitIn)
        var newHeight = newSize.height

        ....

        // That part depends on your approach to placing constraints, it's just my example
        textInputHeightConstraint?.constant = newHeight
        inputContainerHeightConstraint?.constant = newHeight + (interfaceFactory.inputContainerHeight - interfaceFactory.textInputMinimumHeight)
    }
```

**Try to update your code like that:**

```
typingViewHeight = typingView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: typingView.frame.height)
typingViewHeight?.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
typingViewHeight?.isActive = true
```

If it doesn't help, take a look at that answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27522511/5147552

Comment: The code for handling the UITextView's contentSize changing is based off of a lot of other code I have written, so it'll be kind of hard to post that there. I know it works, though, because it worked with the UITextView **before** I added a custom `inputAccessoryView`. My question is, assuming that I'm adjusting the height of the `typingView` (**not** `messageTextView`) correctly, why is it giving me that error and not letting me change the height constraint?